# The .torrent file contains gibberish characters

Tags: vim, bittorrent, torrent

Can someone explain the gibberish characters at the end of every `.torrent` file?

[image: The gibberish torrent]

The picture shows the understandable information along with only a part of the gibberish section. It just seems like the comprehensible part ends so abruptly at the pink pipeline I painted.

By the way, I am viewing it in VIM with UTF-8 encoding, which torrent files should be encoded with if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Why would you expect the files to be human-readable? (BitTorrent files are encoded using a scheme called [Bencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode).)

Comment: After further reading my understanding is:
The delimiters and decimals are always ASCII characters, so I can distinguish these. However everything in between may be any encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are referring to is the value for the dictionary entry with a key of `pieces`. The `6:pieces129140:` before your marked position indicates that the entry's key has a length of 6 characters, which allows us to determine that the key is `pieces`. The `129140` which follows the key is the length of the entry's value, in bytes. This data structure is a result of [bencoding](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Bencoding).

The `pieces` dictionary entry in the `.torrent` file contains the SHA1 hashes for all pieces concatenated into one long string. Hashes are important as they allow the user to ensure the pieces they have downloaded are valid. Using hashes for individual pieces is better than only having the hash for the whole file, as it reduces the wasted data; you don't have to download the *whole* file before your client realises that the data is invalid.

SHA1 hashes consist of 20 bytes, which are stored as raw bytes in the `.torrent` file. This is why the data appears malformed in your editor.

> `pieces` maps to a string whose length is a multiple of 20. It is to be subdivided into strings of length 20, each of which is the SHA1 hash of the piece at the corresponding index.

Taken from [this](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) BitTorrent protocol specification document.

Comment: "dictionary has a key of pieces and has value with a length of 129140 characters", I don't think it's number of characters, but number of bytes.